# SharePoint Online, Classic Mode - Create empty page for custom form?

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-form, publishing-page

I have custom html code with form, and want to use JSOM to create new item.

I want to have completely blank page, but with SharePoint context. How do You usually do it? As I understand I can create minimal.master in Design manager, then create Page layout inherited from this minimal.master, then add page in "Pages" (I have Publishing sites). But this page contains a lot of data- quicklaunch, ribbon..  Of course I can hide these all with CSS, but not sure it is best practice.

How do You use custom html inside SharePoint - create master pages and then delete all unnecessary placeholders? I've read that it could break sync between *.html and *.master files. Or delete them on Page Layout level?.. I also don't understand why I can inherit from "Article", "Welcome Page", etc. types only. I need 'Empty' one..

Answer (score 0):

Argh..

I tried to create content types, minimal master pages, page layouts inherited from this masterpage, researched workarounds to allow html5 there...

And finally did what I always do - added new page in "Site Pages"(note, not "Pages"), added markup and hided SP areas:

```
/* Hide SharePoint Controls */
div#suiteBarDelta,
div#s4-ribbonrow,
div#sideNavBox,
div#s4-titlerow {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Finish.